# Oracle DBMS INSERT Procedure not working

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm working on what should be a simple functionality for my database.

When a user signs up to my application, a field `password_changed` is initialised to 0, upon doing this in my `user trigger` I want to fire the below method to send that new user a message telling them that they should update their password.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_users
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Get the new user id
    IF :NEW.user_id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT seq_user_id.nextval
        INTO :NEW.user_id
        FROM sys.dual;
    END IF;

   -- Alert a user that they need to change their password
   IF :NEW.pass_changed IS NULL THEN
      :NEW.pass_changed := 0;
      send_alert(:NEW.user_id, 'Thank-you for registering, please change your password for security reasons!');
   END IF;
END;
```

This first trigger simply initialises password set to `0` and then calls my send_alert() function, taking the `:NEW.user_id` which gets populated by my sequence.

send_alert() PROCEDURE:

```
-- Sends an alert to the user noting that they haven't changed their password
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_alert( 
   this_user users.user_id%TYPE, 
   this_message STRING 
)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO messages 
   VALUES('', this_user, getSystemId(), 'ALERT', this_message, '', '');
END send_alert;
```

When this code runs, I get the error `integrity constraint (PRCSE.INBOX_MESSAGE_TO_FK) violated - parent key not found` I understand what this means - however the value for the parent key should be populated via `this_user`, if I substitute that field for an existing value the procedure completes and `INSERTS` for the old user.

I can only think that for some reason the `:NEW.user_id` is not getting passed, but I initialise its value before calling my procedure.

**EDIT 10/04/14 13:48 GMT**: To clear any confusion, getSystem() returns the master admin id

```
-- Gets the ID of the SYSTEM user via its unique email
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSystemId 
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    system_user users.user_id%TYPE;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN 
    SELECT user_id
    INTO   system_user
    FROM   users
    WHERE  user_email = 'system@application.com'
    AND    user_permissions = 'ADMIN';
RETURN system_user;
COMMIT;
END getSystemId;
```

Any help would be appreciated - 
Regards, Alex.

Comment: How about an `AFTER INSERT` trigger?

Comment: @OracleUser that was indeed the solution - I'm new to Oracle DB, glad I can see how this particular scenario is solved now though - thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you try to insert value in BEFORE trigger (e.g. before parent row is inserted):

```
SQL> create table t(x int primary key);


SQL> create table t_c(x int references t(x));


SQL> create or replace trigger tr_i
  2  before insert on t
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into t_c(x) values(:new.x);
  6  end;
  7  /

SQL> insert into t values(1);
insert into t values(1)
            *
error in line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C00330529) voilated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: in  "SCOTT.TR_I", line 2 
ORA-04088: error in trigger execution 'SCOTT.TR_I' 


SQL> create or replace trigger tr_i
  2  after insert on t
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into t_c(x) values(:new.x);
  6  end;
  7  /

SQL> insert into t values(1);

1 row inserted.

SQL> select * from t;

     X                                                                          
------                                                                          
     1                                                                          

SQL> select * from t_c;

     X                                                                          
------                                                                          
     1
```

Comment: Ahh I feel so silly - I can't believe I didn't spot that, to clarify, the before trigger prepares all of the values before it will do the INSERT, so even though :NEW.user_id has incremented, it does not yet exist in the table and therefore the key is violated?
Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: Yes, and BTW if you really need some logic of this kind you can use DEFERRED constraint - it will not immideately case exception but wait to be checked untill commit. But it has some drawbacks like less performance.

Comment: Interesting, I may read into that - thanks again for you help.